# dup2() terminates the child process early

Tags: c++, c, process, pipe, dup2

I'm writing a c program to implement multiple pipes but having trouble as dup2 is terminating the child process early. Here is my code:

```
// so you have i number of commands
fcommand = i;
for(i = 0; i < (fcommand - 1); ++i){
    if( pipe(fd + i*2) < 0 ){
        printf("Error!: cannot create file descripters\n");
        exit(5);
    }
}
++i;
printf("%d\n", i);
j = -1;
cdc = 0;
while(i >= 1){
    pid = fork();//creating a child
    if(pid == 0){//i.e. if its a child
        if(i != fcommand){//i.e. if there is a previous command
            if( dup2(fd[(cdc-1)*2], 0) < 0){// 0 -----> stdin
                printf("Error!: cannot duplicate file descriptors\n");
                exit(6);
            }
        }
        if(i != 1){
            if(dup2(fd[cdc*2+1], 1) < 0 ){// this is where the problem occurs
                printf("Error!: cannot duplicate file descriptors\n");
                exit(7);
            }
        }
        k = 0;
        while(k < ((2 * (fcommand - 1))))
            close(fd[k++]);
        ++j;
        if(execvp(in[j].enter[0], in[j].enter) < 0){
            printf("%s: command not found!\n", in[j].enter[0]);
            exit(1);
        }                               
    }
    else{ 
        if(pid < 0){//if error
            printf("Error!: cannot create a new process\n");
            exit(8);
        }
        if(pid > 0){//if a parent
            while(wait(&status) > 0);
            --i;
            cdc++;
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the command the output that I get is the result of the first command and then the program terminates without executing the rest of the commands in the pipe.

Any ideas as to why `dup2` causes my child process to terminate prematurely?

Comment: `dup2(fd[(cdc-1)*2],` it appears `cdc` starts at zero, so cdc-1 will be negative.

Comment: but then it won't go there the first time as i have the condition "if not first command".

Comment: cdc-1 is referenced inside the `i!=fcommand` clause, not the `i!=1` clause.  Your indices are fubar.